# Passing additional data in WebSecurity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, security

I'm using default forms authentication implementation in ASP.NET MVC 4.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
       //Assign additional data
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

This works fine. I need to pass some additional data of each logged in user, to use later, without accessing the database again. (ex: user roles and role details)

Is there any implementation in WebSecurity to do this without using Session variable?

Comment: If you want to use roles for the logged in User, then instead of using [AllowAnonymous] in the action, you can decorate with [ValueNetAuthorize] attribute.

Also you can pass the role permission in this like:
[ValueNetAuthorize(Permissions = Roles.View)]
You should have the permissions defined in Roles entity.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would have additional values to be stored at the time of user registration using the code

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("username", "somepassword", new{DateCreated=DateTime.Now});
```

You can add multiple properties in the anonymous object

`WebSecurity.Login` takes only 2 parameters to login an existing user

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to additional values and parameter websecurity method :

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password,
                        propertyValues: new
                        {
                            NameFamily = model.NameFamily,
                            PostCode = model.PostCode,
                            Address = model.Address,
                            Phone = model.Phone,
                            Lat = model.Lat,
                            Lng = model.Lng
                        });
```