# no overload for method 'Login' takes 4 argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I made some changes in my `AccountModels`. I additionally added a property Role ( a dropdown has value "Admin" & "User"). Now it is showing some error

> no overload for method 'Login' takes 4 argument

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && 
        WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, 
                          model.Password,
                          model.Role, 
                          persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: can you please post "Login" method here?

Comment: Show us how `Login` is called. The error method states that you call it like `Login(model, "", foo, bar);` which is not allowed since it accepts only 2 parameters.

Comment: `WebSecurity.Login` takes 3 arguments.

Comment: oh, is the error about `WebSecurity.Login` or **your** `Login` method?

Comment: Why you want to pass a role as an argument to login method. Role should be a result of login, not its parameter.

Comment: public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        public string Role { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    }
Here is my LoginModel.

Comment: <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Role)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Role)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                </li>

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of login is `WebSecurity.Login(userName, password, persistCookie)`. you are trying to pass 4 arguments

Comment: he said he has overloaded the method

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI Where he said that?

Comment: @jinto Jacob, What should I do in that case to resolve this?

Comment: @VishnuSharma I never tried that but [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716279/passing-additional-data-in-websecurity).

Comment: @JintoJacob, Thanks for this link.